# 1 becomes 0 without toggling the switch in arduino

Tags: arduino

I have connected a toggle switch(a switch that goes up and down not a push button) to my arduino in bit "2". If I toggle it to "down" it remains 0 all throughout but if I toggle it to "up" it becomes "1" but goes to "0" then "1" again. This goes on a cycle until I toggle the switch to "down" again which becomes consistently "0". Below is my code. Thank you.

```
int PrOb2 = 2;
int count = 0;

void setup() {
  Serial.begin(9600);
  pinMode(2, INPUT);
}

void loop() {
  int xOb2 = digitalRead(PrOb2);
  Serial.println(xOb2);
  delay(100);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It's an issue of debounce according to my research i.e. if I am not mistaken. So what I needed to do is just to change the 'INPUT' to 'INPUT_PULLUP'.

Comment: A pullup isn't about debounce.